# UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes Subclass returning nil in custom properties

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have subclassed the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes class and added a few custom properties.

In my custom UICollectionViewLayout class, I am overriding the static 
`+ (Class)layoutAttributesClass`  and I return my new attributes class.

In my UICollectionViewLayout class I override the `-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` and I set the values to the custom properties.

I can inspect the attributes class right there and see that the custom properties are set properly.

So, lastly I need to retrieve these properties in the UICollectionViewCell, so I override the `-(void) applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes` to fetch the values in the custom UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes class, YET they are nil.  As if I never set them.

All the rest of the attributes are working perfectly, including transforms and such.  So clearly, Im doing something wrong.  Please advise.

Included is the HeaderFile of my custom class

```
@interface UICollectionViewLayoutAttributesWithColor : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

@property (strong,nonatomic) UIColor *color;

@end
```

and here is the implementation.  As you can see, nothing special

```
@implementation UICollectionViewLayoutAttributesWithColor

@synthesize color=_color;

@end
```

Comment: Is the layoutattributes object returned an instance of your custom class? Can you include your implantation of the custom class?

Comment: posting updated to include class

Comment: I have this problem as well. Perhaps it is a bug? Nothing in the docs suggest that anything else is necessary.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you will be glad to know the answer is simple. You just need to override copyWithZone: as the UICollectionViewAttributes implements the NSCopying protocol. What's happening is Apple code is making copies of your custom attributes object, but because you haven't implemented copyWithZone, your custom attributes are not being copied to the new object. Here's an example of what you need to do:

```
@interface IRTableCollectionViewLayoutAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    CGRect _textFieldFrame;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect  textFieldFrame;

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    IRTableCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *newAttributes = [super copyWithZone:zone];
    newAttributes->_textFieldFrame = _textFieldFrame;

    return newAttributes;
}
```

Comment: Blimey... That's well found. Just got bitten by this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of dropping custom values is because we have to implement -copyWithZone: because UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes implements and uses NSCopying

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying apply layout attributes to a cell. It can be done like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get Cell
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Apply Attributes
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell applyLayoutAttributes:attributes];

    return cell;
}
```

However, in my implementation of UICollectionView I just added the custom properties to my subclass of UICollectionViewCell not subclass of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes. I think subclassing UICollectionViewCell is more efficient in most cases:

```
@interface ColoredCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIColor *color;
@end

@implementation ColoredCollectionCell
// No need to @synthesize in iOS6 sdk
@end
```

In your collection view controller:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    //Get the Cell
    ColoredCollectionCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Get the color from Array of colors
    UIColor *thisColor = self.colorsArray[indexPath.item];

    //Set cell color
    cell.color = thisColor;

    return cell;

}
```